# Why does my UI break after my laptop has turned off the screen because of inactivity?

Tags: windows-10, window, user-interface, visual-artifacts

I have started to notice this behaviour last week. I use Windows 10 Pro Version 2004 OS build 19041.546. My power options set the screen to be turned off after 15 min of inactivity, and never to enter sleep mode.

When I come back after 15 minutes or more my user interface is screwed like this:

[scrambled interface, some text is fixed after I selected it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kh2ZA.png)

It's not a screen hardware problem because I can screenshot it, and the glitch moves if I move the window, and it doesn't disappear until I force the UI to refresh (for instance, if the title bar of the window is screwed, it gets fixed after I resize the window, or minimize and restore it. When text is affected, selecting the text forces it to refresh and fixes that part). The tilte bar of the window (in this case where the open tabs are) is also affected, but I maximized the window before taking the screenshot so the title bar fixed itself.

In this instance it affected Mozilla Firefox but this can happen to any window of any program (as long as it is being displayed when the glitch happens). I have never seen ithappen to the taskbar or the desktop, this somehow only affects open windows.

I've [checked the RAM](https://www.howtogeek.com/260813/how-to-test-your-computers-ram-for-problems/) using the default settings of the Windows Memory Diagnostic tool but nothing was found there, so if RAM isn't the issue i don't know how to investigate this any further.

This is easy to fix right away and it hasn't caused me any issues, but itis annoying and I want to know the cause so I can be sure that it wont cause problems any further.

Comment: Updated graphics card drivers?

Comment: Yes, I have all my hardware up to date.
Nvidia GeForce GTX 1660 Ti.
-"Device manager" driver version 27.21.14.5167
-"Nvidia control Panel" driver version 451.67

. According to Nvidia website there's a newer version 456.71
https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/165685/en-us

I'll update to it just in case, but this driver has never had any issues and it's from july:
https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/162106/en-us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to let anyone know, I followed @Mokubai's advice, I installed last graphics card driver (found at nvidia's webpage) and that fixed it.

I still don't know what caused the error, but hey, I'm not complaining.